# syntax error : 1064 , when creating a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, syntax

```
CREATE table parent_user
 ( userid int  auto_increment PRIMARY KEY,
 Username varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Password varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    Email varchar(200) NOT NULL

 );
```

EDIT : OK so I made some changes:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `parent_reg` (
pUserName varchar(100)
pPassword varchar(200)
pEmail varchar(200)
)
as
Begin
Declare Count int
Declare ReturnCode int

Select Count = Count(Username)
from parent_user where Username = @Username
If Count > 0
Begin
      Set ReturnCode = -1
    End
    Else
    Begin 
      Set ReturnCode = 1
      insert into parent_user values
      (pUserName, pPassword, pEmail)
    End
    Select pReturnCode as ReturnValue 
    End
```

But I still got the same error-
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'pPassword varchar(200) pEmail varchar(200) ) ....'

The syntax error is at 'pPassword varchar(200)'

Comment: I think it's because of the word "stored", you don't need it. You just need CREATE PROCEDURE

Comment: Also there is a select with a comma in the line above the create procedure which idk what is doing there

Comment: First, your syntax looks like a strange mixture of SQL Server and MySQL.  Second, what is `select * from parent_user,` doing there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in the question is invalid syntax for MySQL Stored Procedure. It looks more like Microsoft SQL Server (Transact SQL) syntax.

Some observations:

MySQL procedure variables cannot start with **`@`** because that character is reserved for user-defined variables.

MySQL doesn't use a `NVARCHAR` type. The setting of the `character_set_client` variable in the session (at the time the procedure is created) is what controls the characterset of the procedure variables.

The line `select * from parent_user,` before the `CREATE PROCEDURE` looks entirely out of place.

Missing semicolons (statement terminators).

The `INSERT` is for a table with four columns; there are only three values and no column list.

If the goal is to create a stored procedure in MySQL, we'd need syntax closer to this:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE parent_reg(p_username VARCHAR(100),
p_password VARCHAR(200), p_email VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE mycount INT;
  DECLARE myreturncode INT;

  SELECT COUNT(pu.username)
    INTO mycount
    FROM `parent_user` pu
   WHERE pu.username = p_username;

  IF (mycount > 0 ) THEN
    SET myreturncode = -1;
  ELSE
    SET myreturncode = 1;
    INSERT INTO `parent_user` (`username`, `password`, `email`)
    VALUES (p_username, p_password, p_email);
  END IF;
  SELECT myreturncode AS `ReturnValue`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's your database's collation. When installing SQL Server and choose your default collation, there's a "case sensitivity" checkbox. Certain collations are case sensitive and will affect your queries (and stored procedures).

A lot of vendors don't test their products on servers with case sensitive collations, which leads to runtime errors.

So just try to choose between "Username" and "UserName"